# how to avoid multiple if-else statements for vaildation in Java

Tags: java, json, if-statement, exception

I have lots of multiple if-else statements. For code optimization, I need to write one function for all if else logic. As of now my code structure is in below.

input request is in JSONObject(org.json.simple.JSONObject), which have more than 10 values.

```
  String s = (String) inputObj.get("test");
  String s1 = (String) inputObj.get("test");
  String s2 = (String) inputObj.get("test");
  String s3 = (String) inputObj.get("test");
        if (s != null && s.trim().isEmpty()) {
            if (s1 != null && s1.trim().isEmpty()) {
                if (s2 != null && s2.trim().isEmpty()) {
                    if (s3 != null && s3.trim().isEmpty()) {
                        if (s4 != null && s4.trim().isEmpty()) {
                           ........
                        } else {
                          return;
                        }
                    } else {
                        return;
                    }
                } else {
                     return;
                }
            } else {
               return;
            }
        } else {
           return;
        }
```

How to avoid this kind of looping and throw an error message in common method.

Advance thanks.

Comment: Have you looked into Java validation framework like javax.validation?

Comment: In javax.validation, for each request i want to create bean and validate it right? for avoiding this i am getting  request as JSONObject.

Comment: You could merge them all into a single if/else with `&&`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class YourClass{
    private boolean isBlankDataPresent(JSONObject inputObj, String[] keys) throws Exception {
        for (String key : keys) {
            String input = (String) inputObj.get(key);
            if( input == null || input.trim().isEmpty())
                throw new Exception(key +" is Empty");
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean validateData(JSONObject inputObj, String[] keys) throws Exception {
        boolean isBlankDataPresent= isBlankDataPresent(inputObj, keys);
        if (!isBlankDataPresent) {
            // do Your Stuff and return true
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: In this case i want to add new validateData() for all request I received?

Comment: If you want a generic method, then you can pass a list of keys also to the validateData() method and validate accordingly

Answer (score 2):

Consider adding all your strings to array or ArrayList of string, and looping thru each entry in it, and check them for null or emptiness.

Comment: can you explain with some example?

Comment: which helps me a lot.

Comment: @Emre Acar's example is what you need

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
void main() {
    List<String> sList = new ArrayList<>();
    sList.add(inputObj.get("test"));
    sList.add(inputObj.get("test"));
    sList.add(inputObj.get("test"));
    sList.add(inputObj.get("test"));

    for(String s : sList){
        try {
            checkString(s);
        }catch (Exception e){
            //log or print the exception, however you like
        }
    }
}
void checkString(String s) throws Exception{
    if(s!= null && !s.trim().isEmpty()){
        //doStuff
    }else{
        throw new Exception("String is null or empty !!!");
    }       
}
```

You should also check [this](http://www.wiki-zero.com/wiki/en/Don't_repeat_yourself) out.

Comment: How can I throw the exception if first name is null or empty?

Comment: @MegalaPerumal i guess i didnt understand what you need. You can just use throw new Exception()

Comment: ya, in JSONObject i will get all the input, i need to validate it, and want to throw the exception for each field. if I have firstname, lasname and consider last name is empty. I want to throw last name is empty. but in your code I can not throw the exception for all individual fields

Comment: fine. But I want to throw which string is empty. like First name is empty, last name is empty, email is empty. How can I do this in above code.

Comment: @MegalaPerumal i'm not going to finish your all homework for you. Try to make progress by yourself.

Comment: I agree. I dont know how to return individual validation. for this reason only i posted the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public Integer checkIsEmapty(String checkingString){
        if(checkingString != null && !checkingString.trim().isEmpty()){
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public String method(){
        String s ="";
        String s1 = "hi";
        String s2 = "java";
        String s3 = null;
        String s4 = null;
       Integer s1i = checkIsEmapty(s);
       Integer s2i = checkIsEmapty(s1);
       Integer s3i = checkIsEmapty(s2);
       Integer s4i = checkIsEmapty(s3);
       Integer s5i = checkIsEmapty(s4);

       Integer total = s1i + s2i + s3i + s4i + s5i;
       switch (total){
           case 1 :
               // To DO
           case 2 :
               // To DO


       }
    }
    in switch used to checking the value, U can pass binary and Integer also
```

Answer (score 0):

Like @Emre Acre mentioned,

```
List<String> sList = new ArrayList<>();
sList.add(inputObj.get("test"));
sList.add(inputObj.get("test"));
sList.add(inputObj.get("test"));
sList.add(inputObj.get("test"));

boolean allDataValid = sList
        .stream()
        .allMatch(s -> s != null && s.trim().isEmpty());

if(allDataValid) {
    ......
} else {
    return;
}
```

Comment: likewise I want to check all the variables?

Comment: It's not Acre -_-